# Como faço para adicionar uma opção de logar pelo Google no meu site?

Tags: php, html, google, login

Tenho um site em PHP e gostaria que o usuário tivesse a opção de entrar com a conta do Google, assim como tem aqui no Stack Overflow, para ele não precisar fazer o cadastro.

Precisaria pegar o nome do Google e Email do usuário

Se quiser ver meu site: http://silly.getenjoyment.net/

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/php

Answer (score -1):

Boas veja as seguintes livrarias php:

- https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-php( Google's officially supported PHP client library for using OAuth 2.0 authorization and authentication with Google APIs.)
- https://github.com/opauth/opauth (Multi-provider authentication framework for PHP )